# CryptoJS Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded in wordArray to ByteArray conversion

Tags: javascript, arrays, encryption, cryptojs

I am trying to implement encryption and decryption in a react client application using CryptoJS. The encryption and decryption can be done without error but it is only for the case of small file size. Errors occurs saying that **Maximum call stack size exceeded** in converting wordArray to ByteArray during decryption of a video file(9MB). The code handling this conversion is from: [GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Prhg.png)

Error: 
[Maximum call stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Prhg.png) [size exceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao6uQ.png)

Code:

```
 wordArrayToByteArray = (wordArray,length) => {

  if(wordArray.hasOwnProperty("sigBytes") && wordArray.hasOwnProperty("words")){
    length = wordArray.sigBytes;
    wordArray = wordArray.words;
  }

  let result = [];
  let bytes;
  let i = 0;

  while(length > 0){
    bytes = this.wordToByteArray(wordArray[i],Math.min(4,length));
    length -= bytes.length;
    result.push(bytes);
    i++;
  }

  return [].concat.apply([],result);
}

 wordToByteArray = (word, length) => {

  var ba = [],
    i,
    xFF = 0xFF;
  if (length > 0)
    ba.push(word >>> 24);
  if (length > 1)
    ba.push((word >>> 16) & xFF);
  if (length > 2)
    ba.push((word >>> 8) & xFF);
  if (length > 3)
    ba.push(word & xFF);

  return ba;
}

decryptFile = (downloaded) =>{ 
  //convert unit array(encrypted file) to string
  let encryptedString = this.uintToString(downloaded);

  //decrypt and get wordArray
  const decrypted = cryptojs.AES.decrypt(encryptedString,"123");
  console.log(decrypted);

  //convert wordArray to string
  let decryptedString = decrypted.toString(cryptojs.enc.Utf8);


  // form a new word array
  const wordArray = cryptojs.enc.Hex.parse(decryptedString);


  //convert new wordArray to byteArray
  return this.wordArrayToByteArray(wordArray,Object.keys(wordArray).length);
}

uintToString = (uintArray) => {
  const decodedStr = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(uintArray);
  return decodedStr;
}

 onDownload = () => {
  ipfs.get(this.state.ipfsHash,(error,files)=>{
    files.forEach((file)=>{
      console.log(file.path);
      const decryptedFile = this.decryptFile(file.content);

      const arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(decryptedFile);

      const blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView],{type: "video/mp4"});
      console.log(blob);
      fileSaver.saveAs(blob,"curseTheInternet.mp4");
    })
  })
}
```

Or any other suggestion of encryption library for client?

Comment: What's the point of that `[].concat.apply()` call? Why not just return `result`

Comment: The decrypted video won't play if I change that to just return **result**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from your use of `[].concat.apply([], result)` if result is too large this will cause the error you're seeing. As far as I can tell you're using this to flatten the array of words. To avoid this error try using [.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Answer (score 1):

Use this improved version

```
static wordArrayToByteArray(wordArray: CryptoJS.lib.WordArray, length: number): Uint8Array {
    let words: any = wordArray;
    if (wordArray.hasOwnProperty("sigBytes") && wordArray.hasOwnProperty("words")) {
      length = wordArray.sigBytes;
      words = wordArray.words;
    }

    let result: number[] = [];
    let bytesAdded;
    let i = 0;
    while (length > 0) {
      bytesAdded = this.wordToByteArray(result, words[i], Math.min(4, length));
      length -= bytesAdded.length;
      i++;
    }
    return new Uint8Array(result);
  }

  private static wordToByteArray(result, word, length): number {
    const lengthBefore = result.length;
    const xff = 0xFF;
    if (length > 0)
      result.push(word >>> 24);
    if (length > 1)
      result.push((word >>> 16) & xff);
    if (length > 2)
      result.push((word >>> 8) & xff);
    if (length > 3)
      result.push(word & xff);
    return result.length - lengthBefore;
  }
```